# Julia's Optim.jl package cannot perform boxed optimization

Tags: optimization, julia

I tried to run an example from `Optim.jl` [documentation](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/#user/minimization/#box-constrianed-optimization):

```
using Optim

f(x) = (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2


function g!(G, x)
G[1] = -2.0 * (1.0 - x[1]) - 400.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2) * x[1]
G[2] = 200.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)
end

lower = [1.25, -2.1]
upper = [Inf, Inf]
initial_x = [2.0, 2.0]
inner_optimizer = GradientDescent()
results = optimize(f, g!, lower, upper, initial_x, Fminbox(inner_optimizer))
```

It returns:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Optim.GradientDescent{LineSearches.InitialPreviou
s{Float64},LineSearches.HagerZhang{Float64},Void,Optim.##43#45} to an object of type Optim.Fminbox
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Optim.Fminbox(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong. It can run if the problem does not use lower and upper bound:

```
 results = optimize(f, g!, initial_x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most probably using Optim version 0.14.1 in which case you should write:

```
optimize(f, g!, initial_x, lower, upper, Fminbox{GradientDescent}())
```

and all goes through cleanly.

The differences with your code are:

- argument order - initial point should be a third argument
- you call `Fminbox` constructor differently

The syntax you are using requies Optim 0.15.1 under which it works fine.